# How to know when to use Dynamic Programming?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given any problem, how do I know whether it is solvable using Dynamic Programming? For example: consider [the rod cutting problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-13-cutting-a-rod/). Now, how do I know whether dynamic programming will give me an optimal answer? Basically my question is: how do I check if a problem follows the "Principle of Optimality" - that optimal solution of every problem involves the optimal solution of a sub problem. And are there any problems that *don't* follow this principle? (If there aren't, my original question becomes redundant, of course!)

Comment: I think this is too broad a question. How do you check if DP is a good idea? I can hardly give better advice than: contemplate the problem statement.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it is. But it'd be of great help if you could describe with some examples - I don't really know how to frame this question better. I really want to know how to check if the problem at hand follows the principle of Optimality.

Comment: The main challenge here is how to split a problem into sub-problems; this question is very hard to answer, and I think that there is no general way to do this. There are examples of really ingenious transformations that move the problem in question to an entirely different space where indeed it shows a sub-problem structure (I remember there was a nice programming contest task like this, but I can't recollect the details right now). The point is that without the transformation it would be rather hard to guess that this problem can be solved using DP.

Comment: I DO NOT think this is too broad a question. Principle of optimality generally does hold for problems with non-separable performance indices. Yet sometimes it still does. When and why is a mathematically valid research topic. I am looking for refs on this right now and would probably already had my answers if this question would not had been closed. Overzealous closing hurts the utility of this community.

Answer (score 3):

A nice example of problem which does not follow the principle of optimality is the "longest simple path". This is: given a graph $G$ and two vertices $v$ and $w$, which is the longest simple path from $v$ to $w$ (in terms of the number of edges)?

A easy example to see that this fails is when your graph is a cycle.